# Auto download link in email to folder on Google drive

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

Our provider send reports vai email with a link to pdf instead of as an attachment

Any ways I can automate this so it downloads directly to my Google drive?

Comment: I don't see any Google Scripts or other solutions that currently allow for that. You could probably code one -- check the email body, if it contains a PDF link (could also filter by sender) open the link. Not sure if you could get the script to auto-save the PDF but you should at least be able to get it to open it in a new tab or window.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct way but you could try this -

[Append the URL of the web hosted PDF file to Google Docs Viewer service](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2016/10/how-to-save-online-pdf-office-docs.html) -
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url={https://somesite.com/report.PDF}

[image]

After that file is opened within the browser, click the "Save to Drive" icon (as shown in the screenshot) in the header of Google Docs Viewer to save it to your Google Drive.

Rather than type the Google Docs Viewer URL every time, you can re-purpose the Chrome custom search engine configuration option to invoke the Google Docs Viewer URL with an assigned keyword like "V". Once configured (see [detailed steps](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2013/11/a-simpler-way-to-configure-custom.html)) you can type V in the Chrome address bar, hit tab, paste the URL of the report